# angular 6 click not working html code present in typescript file

Tags: javascript, angular, methods, angular6

This question maybe asked, but it is not resolve my issue. I have `Angular 6` project. In my ts component I added `button` tag. And I try to call `remove` method, but it is not working.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
declare var $:any;

@Component({templateUrl: 'login.component.html'})
export class detectionRuleComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    addNewRow(){
        var new_row = `<button (click)="remove($event)">Remove</button>`;
    }

    remove(){
        alert();
    }
}
```

here when I click remove button alert() not coming. Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have added a template in one method?

If you want to show the remove button in your template just do like this.

In this component `login.component.html`

```
<button (click)="remove($event)">Remove</button>;
```

Then in your TS write only your logic.

```
remove(event) {    
    alert(event);
}
```

And a question why do you need the jQuery tag `$` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your  answer. Actually I try to add dynamically add and remove  row. thanks why am using html tag inside ts

Comment: @RameshS then add your HTML code to see what are you trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

Angular works in such a way that if you inject an HTML snippet through the ts file for manipulating DOM, Angular doesn't register that directives inside the snippet you injected. Hence it is best practice to not manipulate DOM like that!
So for your issue, your remove method has not been registered at all for the click directive thus doesn't get called. It also doesn't have a proper parameter.

```
<!--HTML--->
<button (click)="addCicked($event)">Add</button>

<div *ngIf="isNewRowAdded">
 <button (click)="removeCicked($event)">remove</button>
</div>
```

```
addCicked(event){
  this.isNewRowAdded = true;
}

removeCicked(event){
  alert('Remove Clicked')
}
```

And if you really want to manipulate DOM directly you can use ElementRef for that!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Actually I try to add dynamically add and remove row. thanks why am using html tag inside ts so please help me to solve my issue